# Function Creation in R

Tags: r, function

How do I turn this in a function?

X is a var and Z are the different datasets

```
X<-as.factor(X)
niveis<-levels(X)
teste<-table(X)

for(i in 1:length(niveis)) {
Z$weight[X == niveis[i]] <- teste[niveis[i]]
                       }

Z$weight<-as.numeric(Z$weight)
```

I've been trying:

```
weight_function<-function(Z, X) {

  X<-as.factor(X)
  niveis<-levels(X)
  teste<-table(X)

for(i in 1:length(niveis)) {
  Z$weight[X == niveis[i]] <- teste[niveis[i]]
                           }
  Z$weight<-as.numeric(Z$weight)

}
```

But nothing happens and no error is shown

Comment: I recommend reading https://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-inflammation/02-func-R/ https://www.statmethods.net/management/userfunctions.html or https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/functions-in-r-a-tutorial or any other the other top hits on google if you write "function create in R". Objects in the function are local to the function - so for example `Z$weight` set inside the function will not be set after the function is called

Answer (score 1):

R functions don't (normally) work by side effects. Your function returns nothing. It mutates its local copy of `Z` but then discards the changes. Instead, *return* the mutated copy:

```
weight_function<-function(Z, X) {

  X<-as.factor(X)
  niveis<-levels(X)
  teste<-table(X)

  for(i in 1:length(niveis)) {
    Z$weight[X == niveis[i]] <- teste[niveis[i]]
  }
  Z$weight<-as.numeric(Z$weight)
  Z
}
```

Then call it like `Z <- weight_function(Z, X)`